# Wooden puzzle with multiple balls on strings attached to a central hook, from which metal arms connect top and bottom

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

I bought this puzzle few years ago at a market. I couldn't solve it since. I started to think it was wrongly assembled, therefore can not be solved. Tried to find the solution on the internet/YouTube but no success. What is this puzzle? How can I solve it?
[image: odd puzzle]

Comment: The goal is to remove the brown ball I suppose?

Comment: @justhalf This was my assumption, too. But no instructions came with the puzzle.